# Linear combinations and their spans in $R^{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I came across this exercise:

Can every vector in $\mathbb R^4$ be written as a linear combination of the columns of matrix $B?$ Do the columns of $B$ span $\mathbb R^3$?

$$
   B=     \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 4 & 1 &\ 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 3 &-4 \\
        0 & 2 & 6 & \ 7 \\
        2 & 9&5&-7
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
 I attempted the question by first writing that to ask whether every vector in $\mathbb R^4$ be written as a linear combination of the columns of matrix $B$ is equivalent to asking whether the corresponding linear system has many solutions. Then I reduced the matrix to RREF and found that I had two free variables and two basic variables and the linear system has infinitely many solutions and therefore the columns of the matrix span every vector in $\mathbb R^4$.

Questions:

1. Is this correct? And how do I show it spans $\mathbb R^3$?
2. If a linear combination spans $\mathbb R^n$ then does it also necessarily span $\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

Comment: Take the determinant of the matrix. If it is non-zero, these vectors span $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: @Red Have I answered your answer?  If so, you should hit the checkmark left of it.  If not, what would you like me to elaborate on?

Comment: @Bye_World Yes you have thank you. I had forgotten to check it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that elementary row operations preserve the row space of a matrix (row space = span of rows).  Likewise elementary column operations preserve the column space.  So let's do some e.c.o.'s.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 4 & 1 &\ 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 3 &-4 \\
        0 & 2 & 6 & \ 7 \\
        2 & 9&5&-7
        \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 &\ 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 3 &-4 \\
        0 & 2 & 6 & \ 7 \\
        2 & 1&3&-9
        \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 &\ 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 & \ 15 \\
        2 & 1&0&-5
        \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0&0 \\
        0 & 2 & 15&0 \\
        2 & 1&-5&0
        \end{bmatrix}$$

These three nonzero columns are clearly linearly independent therefore the column space is $3$-dimensional.  So your columns do NOT span $\Bbb R^4$.  Which means that not every vector in $\Bbb R^4$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of this matrix.

---

Does that mean they span $\Bbb R^3$?  That's a little complicated.  It depends on how one defines $\Bbb R^n$.

If you define $\Bbb R^3$ as the set of all $3\times 1$ column matrices then no amount of $4\times 1$ matrices can span it.

On the other hand, *any* $3$d vector space over the reals is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$.  This leads some mathematicians to decide that there is really only $1$ $3$d vector space over the reals -- it just goes by a lot of different names.

I'm inclined to think that in your linear algebra $1$ class, your professor will probably be using the first definition.  But the only way to know for sure is to go ask him/her/the grader.

Comment: You can consider $\mathbb R^3$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ since it is isomorphic to any $3$-dim subspace of $\mathbb R^4$. In that case, since the columns span $3$-dim subspace, the answer would be yes. If you only accept some canonical (?) embedding $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^4$ (for example, by setting the fourth coordinate to $0$), then the answer is obviously no. And finally, if you only accept $\mathbb R^3$ as space of functions $f: 3\to \mathbb R$, then your argument is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In essence what the question is asking is whether the vectors in $\bf B$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Since using RREF one finds that 3 vectors are only linearly independent, the answer is no. With 1 vector in the null space, there are only 3 vectors in the image of the matrix, and thus $\bf B$ only spans a cube in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

In order to span the full $\mathbb{R}^4$ you need 4 basis vectors, and you only have 3. So you are correct. And yes, a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ also spans the $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

**EDIT: My last sentence is wrong, it actually does not span the $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.**

Comment: Your last sentence is wrong.

Comment: Really? A basis that spans the R^n doesn't always span the R^(n-1)? That doesn't make sense to me though

Comment: By definition of span a basis of vector space $V$ spans $V$.  That's the only space it spans.  That's why when a professor asks you "what space does $\{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}$ span?" there is a unique answer.

Comment: But if you take the 4 dimensional standard basis for instance, then the first three vectors span a cube in the 4 dimensional space right? So wouldn't that span the R^3 right there?

Comment: It would span a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$ that is *isomorphic* to $\Bbb R^3$ (that is an object which has all the important properties of $\Bbb R^3$).  But $(1)$ that doesn't really make it $\Bbb R^3$ (though some mathematicians might fight me on that point) and $(2)$ as soon as you add that fourth basis vector, the span is no longer that $3$d subspace, but the $4$d space $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: Oh interesting, so the fact that the cube floats in 4 dimensional space instead of being in itself only a cube makes it different to the R^3? In other words the 4th zero in (1, 0, 0, **0**) makes the difference?

Comment: That's correct.  Just think about it: is $(1,0,0,0)$ the exact same object as $(1,0,0)$? Or even better is $(1)$ the same as $(1,0)$? Of course not.

Comment: Ah thats interesting :D And yeah that makes sense now that I think abut it. Thanks I learned something!

Comment: No problemo. :)